# Why I am getting 404 error on reloading localhost in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have seen many related question on this but none of them helped me to resolve this issue.

I have created my routing as app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [  
 { path: 'home', component: LandingpageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'trade-order', component: TradeOrderComponent},
 { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];


@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

I have created the whole project and build the project with

```
ng build --prod
```

with above code dist folder is created and then after I host this folder on IIS

When i try to access with www.test.com it redirect automatically to www.test.com/home as default page i set as home on route but when I try to reload same URL it display me 404 error.

So I have created file name with .htaccess and in that written text as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

But it did not worked for me .
Do I need to replace {REQUEST_FILENAME} with some other name or do I need to make some change on IIS?

Do I need to replace .htaccess code with some other code.

You can relate my question same as [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8788) or as [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5113)

I know I will get negative marks on this but to me real I am not able to understand the answer written on different post.

Update 1

As suggested by Nanotage I have created web.config an wrote code as

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
<rules>
  <rule name="Redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/home" />
    <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
    </rule>
</rules>
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

image as [image: Folder Pic]

Comment: You added a auth guard for home route, so only logged in user can visit the link. May be you are trying to achieve, if a user is logged in -> then if he visit the page again without log out, he should redirect to 'home' route, right. this is not the logic for that

Comment: @AkhilAravind my actual question is when I refreshed the URL it gives me browser 404 page error

Comment: your auth guard is redirect page to 404 route

Comment: Please share your implementation for the `AuthGuard`. There could be something in there that's navigating the user to a non-existent path. Although your router config should have handled it. Would it be possible for you to provide a sample stackblitz replicating this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A `.htaccess` file is what the apache web server uses. On IIS it's handled by a `web.config` file.

I host an angular application on an IIS server, and we use this `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/HelloWorld/" />
        <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
        </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

(shamelessly stolen from [Hosting an Angular Web application in IIS server](http://sundeepkamath.in/posts/hosting-angular-application-in-iis-server/))

Remember you can also add this file to your `angular.json` file as an asset, and it will be automatically included in the dist directory when you build.

Comment: do we need to replace {REQUEST_FILENAME} with som ething else?

Comment: I have updated the code as u said but none work for me, can you help me out